# Django Rest Framework: Function Based API serializers

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, api-design

Unsolicited for I've been put on an API-project where the requirements are:

- Django
- Django Rest Framework
- Python 3.5
- API needs to be function based (so no classes)

Where the goal is an API that returns data (so I only need 'Read' from CRUD-design principles) in JSON format for internal use by displays.

Django itself has to connect to a default database and a legacy MYSQL data (this works). I've done so with the `settings.py` file.

I then created a new application called `museum_api`; this works as well.

After that I built my models of the legacy database with the help of `python manage.py inspectdb --database=museum_data > models.py` 
the above code generated a python file with classes for every table in the MYSQL database in the rootfolder called 'musart' of the project (this folder holds: manage.py, musart and museum_api.)

Then I created a static JSON response by going inside of the folder called museum_api and created a file: `views.py` and `urls.py`

I left these empty for a sec and went back to the root-folder and into the inner-project folder to edit the urls.py file in there. In that file I added:

```
url(r'', include('museum_api.urls')),
```

The intent is that the API is the first thing people encounter when visiting that subdomain. This too works fine.

Then I went back to the folder `museum_api` and edited the `views.py` file to create two static JSON responses as a test:

```
from rest_framework import status, renderers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

@api_view(['GET'])
def view(request):
    return Response({"name": "HERMÄNN", "test":"mytest"})

@api_view(['GET'])
def hello_world(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("""Hello, httpresonse is here!""")
```

Next up I edited the `urls.py` file inside: museum_api:
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view$', views.view, name='view'),
    url(r'^hello$', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Up until this point I understood all of the documentation; and whenever I run the server and go to the url I get what I expect either the Indexfile, or two JSON responses.

For the past few days I've been stuck with making the API interactive... which is the whole point of the project... All projects and tutorials I found use classes, which violate one of the core requirements.

At this stage I have only questions, no working code...

1) The next step would be to create one function per api-method. An example of this is a function to query all artist with an api method called: `artist`. One of the parameters it should take is 'country'. A possible way of requesting the data to the api is: `url?artist;format=json;country=france`
I'd think of something like this (pseudocode):

```
def artist_api(request):
    data = select * from artists where country = 'france';
    return (data)
```

2) In museum_api > views.py: Why do I need to put an `@api_view['GET']` before every new function? If I leave it out, that function stops working.

3) How do I write my serializers so that if the api gets a request (such as with the country example) the python script know what database(s) to query and to return the correct data?

4) Related to 3: Where do I need to create a serializers.py script? In the root folder where my models.py is? Or in the application folder?

Sorry for the long question.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

> 2) In museum_api > views.py: Why do I need to put an @api_view['GET']
>   before every new function? If I leave it out, that function stops
>   working.

The `@api_view` decorator tells your view respond to the HTTP methods mentioned. See the [drf docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) for details.

> 3) How do I write my serializers so that if the api gets a request
>   (such as with the country example) the python script know what
>   database(s) to query and to return the correct data?

Your views will use the database(s) specified in the `DATABASES` setting in your `settings.py`.

In case you are using multiple databases, you will need to set up [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE_ROUTERS) or you can manually select a database to query using using() [See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)]

> 4) Related to 3: Where do I need to create a serializers.py script? In
>   the root folder where my models.py is? Or in the application folder?
>   The usual structure is

```
application
    -- app1
      --- models.py
      --- serializers.py
      --- views.py
    -- app2
      --- models.py
      --- serializers.py
      --- views.py
    -- application
      --- settings.py
      --- urls.py
    -- manage.py
```